# lua: TextRPG.lua:15: attempt to call global 'command' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

I know this one has been asked but I cant find anything that helps, heres my code:

```
print("Welcome to Text RPG \n");
function commmand()
print("What do you want to do? \(\"help\" for help\) \n NOTE: MUST BE IN CAPS")
input = io.read()
--condition = input == "HELP" or input == "EAST" or input == "WEST" or input =="NORTH" or                     input == "SOUTH" or input == "SHOP"
     if input == "HELP" or input == "EAST" or input == "WEST" or input =="NORTH" or input==             "SOUTH" or input == "SHOP" then
      --Future game code
    end
    end
    command()
```

I tried searching but I couldent find an answer, I even made an account just to ask this

Answer (score 1):

```
print("Welcome to Text RPG \n");
function command()
    print("What do you want to do? \(\"help\" for help\) \n NOTE: MUST BE IN CAPS")
    input = io.read()
    --condition = input == "HELP" or input == "EAST" or input == "WEST" or input =="NORTH" or input == "SOUTH" or input == "SHOP"
        if input == "HELP" or input == "EAST" or input == "WEST" or input =="NORTH" or input== "SOUTH" or input == "SHOP" then
            --Future game code
        end
end
command()
```

You need to change:

```
function commmand()
```

to

```
function command()
```

Note the removed `m`.

Comment: @user2400186 Use a different font :)

Comment: I don't think you need to escape the parenthesis while using `print()`